# how to store sentences (words) wit h spaces in an single array in cpp dynamically

Tags: c++

```
int main() 
{
    key[100];
    int i = 0, t = 0;
    cout << "Enter the Keyword      :";
    while (t < 3)
    {
        cin.getline(key, 100);
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    cout << key[0] << endl;
}
```

I used this code. But it returns only a character of the word.Please say how to get a single word in array one by one.

Comment: Do you really need to use an array? In `c++` the good code would likely include `std::vector<std::string>` and not an array at all.

Comment: The key array has no type. Would this program even compile?

Comment: It's been a while, but the call to `std::cin.getline()` is also problematic, as it leaves no room for the null character. Also the use of a magic number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // 3 strings of 100 char max (+1 nullchar)
  char key[3][101];

  int i = 0;

  std::cout << "Enter the Keyword      :\n";

  while(i < 3) {
    std::cin.getline(key[i],100);
    i++;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::cout << key[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Alternative anwser using C++ vector and string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // array of strings
  std::vector<std::string> keyw_list;

  // string for temporary operations
  std::string keyw;

  std::cout << "Enter the Keyword      :\n";

  while(key_list.size() < 3) {
    std::cin >> keyw;
    keyw_list.push_back(keyw);
  }

  for(size_t i = 0; i < keyw_list.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << keyw_list[i] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//include it for istringstream
#include<sstream>

int main ()
{
  string inputString;
  cout << "Enter String:" << endl;
  getline (cin, inputString);

  //Crete object of istringstream and initialize assign input string
  istringstream iss (inputString);

  string word;
  //Extract each words only..no spaces.
  //This way it can handle any
  //special characters.

  while (iss >> word)
    {
      //Display words
      cout << word.c_str () << endl;
    }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: It would be better if answers didn't use bad practices like `using namespace std;`. You also don't have to convert a `std::string` to a C-string to print it with `std::out`.